# if / else statement javascript, loop error

Tags: javascript

This is driving me literally nuts and I cannot figure out why. I am making a reservation system that displays available time blocks (unbooked time in gCalendar), divides it, and displays it according to an allotted time.

```js
document.getElementById("availability").innerHTML = "";
var events = resp.items;
var time_sort = 30;
if (events.length > 0) {
  document.getElementById("availability").innerHTML = "";
  for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var event = events[i];
    var event2 = events[i + 1];
    var d1 = new Date(event.end.dateTime);
    var d2 = new Date(event2.start.dateTime);
    var diff = d2 - d1;
    diff = Math.floor(diff / 60e3)
    if (diff >= time_sort) {
      var loop = Math.floor(diff / time_sort);
      var whenStart = new Date(d2 - time_sort * 60000);
      var whenEnd = new Date(d2);
      document.getElementById("availability").innerHTML += ("Available" +
        "\t" + loop + "\t" + whenStart + "\t\t" + whenEnd + "\t" + '<button>Reserve</button>' + "<br />");

    } else {
      whenStart = event.start.dateTime;
      whenEnd = event.end.dateTime;
    }
    if (!whenStart) {
      whenStart = event.start.date;
    }
  }
} else {
  document.getElementById("availability").innerHTML += "No upcoming events found.";
}
});
});
```

When running the above code, I get a nice result.

> Available 8   Sat Sep 19 2015 11:30:00 GMT+0800 (CST)     Sat Sep 19 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST) Reserve
>   Available 2   Sat Sep 19 2015 13:30:00 GMT+0800 (CST)     Sat Sep 19 2015 14:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST) Reserve
>   Available 2   Sun Sep 20 2015 09:30:00 GMT+0800 (CST)     Sun Sep 20 2015 10:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST) Reserve
>   Available 2   Sun Sep 20 2015 11:30:00
>   GMT+0800 (CST)        Sun Sep 20 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST) Reserve

However, I want to expand all the available time blocks. For example, 10:00-10:30, 10:30-11:00, 11:00-11:30, 11:30 - 12:00 and so forth.

The number of time chunks available is denoted by the variable loop (printed above 8, 2, 2, 2) and it goes backwards (the printed time is actually the last block of time of the available time block).

I thought I could use a simple for loop after `var loop = Math.floor(diff / time_sort);` but I only get one of the available time blocks expanded 8 times -- the one ending at 12:00.

Comment: You have some extra `});` lines at the end of the script, so the snippet doesn't run. You also left out the HTML.

Comment: You really haven't stated a question... at least, not an explicit question. As it stands, this post is too broad...

Comment: A `for` loop should work. Add what you tried to the question, and we should be able to tell what you did wrong.

Comment: This is part of a function that calls google's calendar API so I cannot post the entire code. I added a simple for loop - for (i = 0; i <= loop; i++) after var loop=Math.floor and ended it after document.getelementById